# HotTowel Angular Breeze config not defined

Tags: angularjs, undefined, config, breeze, hottowel

I am following the HotTowel Angular course by John Papa with the latest Hot Towel version 2.1.0, however I am getting an Error "config is not defined" occurring when my query is executed.

```
 function getServerPartials() {
        var orderBy = 'Activated, Label, Serial, IsActive';
        var servers;

        return EntityQuery.from('Servers')
            .select('ServerId, Name, Serial, Activated, IsActive')
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .toType('Server')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .to$q(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            servers = data.results;
            log('Retrieved [Server Partials] from remote data source', servers.length, true);
            return servers;
        }

    }
    function _queryFailed(error) {
        var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Error retreiving data.' + error.message;
        logError(msg, error);
        throw error;
    }

app.run(['$route','config.breeze',  function ($route) {
    // Include $route to kick start the router.       

}]);
```

The error has to do with the .to$q(querySucceeded, _queryFailed); do I have to add something in the app section as I know breeze.to$q library is no longer needed or present.

Comment: Try clicking on the error in Chrome Dev tools so it jumps you to the line number it's originating from. Include what is on that line in the question.

Comment: This is the message I get in chrome: <Object {exception: ReferenceError, cause: undefined}
cause: undefined
exception: ReferenceError
message: "config is not defined">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `getServerPartials` function uses `config` which is an angular service in the app. You need to inject config in your factory, controller, directive, whatever. Otherwise you get this issue. I do not see what type of object the function is contained within. In other words ... if its wrapped in a factory, inject config.

Comment: Thanks John that seems to have solved the problem.       angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['config','common','entityManagerFactory', datacontext]); function datacontext(config, common, emFactory) { –

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
app.run(['$route','config.breeze',  function ($route) {
// Include $route to kick start the router.       
}]);
```

Config is not defined. You have to define it. It also needs to have a property, "breeze", with presumably some really specific stuff you tutorial tells you how to hook up.

Comment: unfortunately the tutorial I'm following doesn't use the config.breeze parameter. The tutorial was based on an earlier version of HotTowel and it used the breeze.to.$q.js library which is no longer required. I haven't found an updated example as of yet.

Comment: Ok, just try:
    ` app.run(['$route',  function ($route) {
     // Include $route to kick start the router.       
     }]);`

Comment: Removing config.breeze gives Q is undefined. Are you missing Q.js?.. I expect config.breeze is required since it is the default setting when you install HotTowel.

Comment: config.breeze is a factory that sets up breeze for angular (including some q stuff). It is in a file called config.breeze.js in the root of the HotTowel app.

Comment: Here is a note at the Breeze web site explaining how to use config.breeze: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service

Answer (score 0):

If you are following John's Pluralsight examples, you may have your app.run in the wrong place.  It looks like you have it in your datacontext.js.  In the PS course, John calls it at the end of the app.js like so:  (the config.js does not have a breeze property in either the Part 1 or part 2 versions)

```
     // Handle routing errors and success events
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$q', 'routemediator',
    function ($route, $rootScope, $q, routemediator) {
        // Include $route to kick start the router.
        breeze.core.extendQ($rootScope, $q);
        routemediator.setRoutingHandlers();
    }]);
```

Comment: Correct in the course it is as above, I included the app.run code in the same code segment for brevity but I do have that section in the app.js file. It must be something quite simple but I haven't found an example which uses config.breeze instead of the breeze.to.$q.js. The config.breeze parameter is introduced in the updated HotTowel version.

Comment: I guess I haven't started an app from scratch with the latest Hot Towel.  But doesn't Hot Towel create a config file?  Perhaps it does not over-write an existing config, if you already had one, and that's why you don't have it.  I'd try just starting a new app with hot towel and seeing what config.js looks like.  Will follow this with interest.

Comment: I'm looking at both the previous config.js and the current one and I don't think it has changed at all. John Papa has introduced this new file config.breeze which cleans up the $q stuff. Also looking at the breeze documentation they may be moving to a breeze service type configuration with angular soon and this will make updating Hot Towel easier. (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs)  Hopefully John could comment on what changes need to be made to use config.breeze, I've reproduced the error on two seperate projects starting from scratch.